# javascript map function to strip comma and keep unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, map-function

I have the following map function to strip each element in the object of their commas if it exists.

```
var items = ['mum, dad', 'uncle, dad', 'brother, sister'];
var clean = [];
clean = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.split(',');
});
```

The problem is that I don't get the expected outcome. My `clean` output is the same as `items` output.
It should be like:

```
console.log(items) //  ['mum, dad', 'uncle, dad', 'brother, sister']
console.log(clean) //  ['mum', dad', 'uncle', dad', 'brother', sister']
```

there is also another point, how can I get the unique values only, as you can see, once they are stipped of their commas, some values are repeated, like  `dad`, how can I keep only one?

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map()` instead of filter and ES6 `Set` to return only unique elements.

```js
var items = ['mum, dad', 'uncle, dad', 'brother, sister'];
var clean = [...new Set([].concat(...items.map(e => e.split(', '))))]

console.log(clean)
```

For IE and other older versions of browsers you can use this solution.

```js
var items = ['mum, dad', 'uncle, dad', 'brother, sister'];
var clean = [].concat.apply([], items.map(function(e) {
  return e.split(', ');
})).filter(function(e) {
  return !this[e] ? this[e] = 1 : false;
}, {})

console.log(clean)
```

Comment: this is very nice, but i get an error in IE browser! could you give the equivalent in normal javascript supported by IE please?

Answer (score 2):

Filter only return those elements which have value true for that particular function. If you want to do some operation/manipulation on each item, then you have to go for map. Try to be as simple as possible, you just have to map each element, split it, and then append it into array clean. Lets have a look at this simple piece of code.

```js
function uniqueArray2(arr) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++)
        if (a.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1 && arr[i] !== '')
            a.push(arr[i]);
    return a;
}
var items = ['mum, dad', 'uncle, dad', 'brother, sister'];
var clean = [];
items.map(function(item) {
  var splitArray = item.split(',');
  for(var i=0; i<splitArray.length; i++){
    clean.push(splitArray[i]);
  }
});
clean = uniqueArray2(clean);
console.log (clean)
```

Comment: great but how can you remove the repeated values?

Comment: I added a simple js function for unique array, so it runs in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `filter` instead of `map`.

Using `map` will return you an array of arrays. If ES6 isn't an option, you can merge it into a single array and remove duplicates like this:

```
var items = ['mum, dad', 'uncle, dad', 'brother, sister'];
var clean = [];
clean = items.filter(function(item) {
 return item.split(',');
});
var merged = [].concat.apply([], clean);
var unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Comment: Even though your suggestion should be implemented, that still wouldn't filter out duplicates.